# How to only fetch only the new row from MySql automatically?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, chat

I am making a messaging service for my users. I used AJAX for sending the message without refreshing the message. I want to fetch the new row from the database automatically (if the current user or the other side user enters any message), without refreshing the older messages.

```
<div id="readmsg">
#The messages is to be read  here....
</div>

<textarea placeholder="Write your message.." id="msg"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="sendmsg">


<?php $user1 = 1; $user2 = 2; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sendmsg").on("click",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var usera = <?php echo $user1.";";?>
      var userb = <?php echo $user2.";";?>
      var msg = $("#msg").val();
      $.ajax({
        url : "sendmessageprocess.php",
        type : "POST",
        data : {message:msg, user1:usera, user2:userb},
        success : function(data){
          document.getElementById("msg").value="";
          $("#msg").val("");
        }
      });
    })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: how do you currently check for new messages in your code?

Comment: (N.B. A real-time chat application will be a lot more efficient when implemented using websockets, or a combination of AJAX and Server-Sent Events. An AJAX-only solution can work, but will be inefficient because the client has to keep polling the server for new messages regularly, without knowing whether any new messages are actually available. What I'm saying is, you should consider whether you want to implement this feature a different way.)

Answer (score 0):

As I see in comments the friends only complicated your problem and be far from your main problem

as a chatroom creator in past, I will seriously offer you to use another technologies instead of ajax

But if it's necessary to use ajax, the best way for solving your problem is:

after fetching new messages in your query, put the last row id in a some index in sessions or cookies such as:

```
$_SESSION['last_msg_id'] = $row['id'];
```

and in another requests get the messages that their ids is more than your last_msg_id

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `id` > "' . $_SESSION['last_msg_id'] . '"';
```

and, for new clients that haven't your session index get last 10 messages for example and create your session index by the told way. example:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['last_msg_id'])){
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `id` > "' . $_SESSION['last_msg_id'] . '"';
}else{
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `messages` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 10';
}
// your query process
$rows = {your rows};
foreach($rows as $row){
    $_SESSION['last_msg_id'] = $row['id'];
}

// or

$rows = {your rows};
$last_row = end($row);
$_SESSION['last_msg_id'] = $last_row['id']
```